# vim LateX-Suite indentation and line breaking

Tags: indentation, vim, wrap

I'm now setting up Vim for use with LaTeX. This is about setting up the indentation. In the picture below, there are many things that need tweaking. Everything between `\vskip .5cm` and `\vskip 1in` is just one hard line (as opposed to 3 soft-wrapped lines).
[image]

1. I want the soft-wrapped lines to follow the original indentation, in this case, the indentation of `Once upon a time...`
2. At the right side of the screenshot, `computer` and `called` are badly broken. If they don't fit the line width, they might as well move to the next (soft) line altogether. **UPDATE:** Now I have this fixed with `set linebreak`.

**Current settings**
My pertinent settings in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim` are

```
set ts=4
set sw=4
set autoindent
set linebreak
```

**Solutions I've tried**
Upon reading `:help autoindent`, I find that I can use `gqgq` to format the current hard line, like so:
[image]

The single hard line now becomes 4 hard lines. However, that's not what I want. I believe that what I'm looking for is **soft wrapping with proper indentation**. Can I do that in Vim? How?

Comment: This was discussed a while ago [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim) without finding a solution. I don't know whether recent updates to `vim` have changed this.

Comment: @mas, it's actually more than a while already, ~2009, `:(`

Comment: See the patch at https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Aditya wrote, there is a patch of mine at https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent . It looks like this (left without, right with): [image: screenshot]

Comment: I have just found this and applied it successfully to MacVim. Eudoxos, you deserve a gold medal for this!

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel, though I would be even happier if it were integrated upstream. To say the least, they are reluctant and I gave up persuading them (I mean, him...) :-|

Comment: Thats a pity, really. Given that it has been on the TODO list for ... how many years? I guess its been since 2004, at least.

Answer (score 5):

The breakintent feature has been finally merged into vim, see https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent.

You can now simply use

```
set breakindent
```

or combine it with other methods like

```
set showbreak=..
```

to get an additional indent.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

An update on this issue:

(citing this page: https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent)

The official patch to this wrapping problem had been released. I put my distribution of Vim on line through Github: https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim-Win

In the latest commit (as of 2014-07-24), I documented how I managed to "sudo-patch" my Vim. The distribution online is working fine for me.

Happy Vimming!